# How do I prevent duplication in my text file when asking for registration from customer in python

Tags: python, text

My codes looks like this

```
def registers():
    print("\n-------------Register-------------")
    new_acc = open("register_file.txt", "a")
    new_acc_read = open("register_file.txt", "r")
    new_uname = input("Enter new username: ")
    username = []
    for line in new_acc_read:
        user = line.split()
        username.append(user[0])
        print(username)
    if new_uname in username:
        print("Username already exists.")
        new_uname = input("Enter new username: ")
    new_acc.write(new_uname)
    new_pass = input("Enter new password: ")
    if len(new_pass) < 8:
        print("Make sure password is at least 8 characters")
        new_pass = input("Enter new password: ")
    elif re.search("[0-9]", new_pass) is None:
        print("Make sure password has a number in it")
        new_pass = input("Enter new password: ")
    elif re.search("[a-z, A-Z]", new_pass) is None:
        print("Make sure password has letter in it")
        new_pass = input("Enter new password: ")
    print("Register successful! Proceed to login.")
    new_acc.write(new_uname + " " + new_pass)
    new_acc.write("\n")
```

I try this to prevent duplication of same usernames but everytime I rerun or when I login to an account that does not exist and return to the registers page I am able to use the same username and in my text file it turns out to be duplicated

```
wewewewe wewe12345
wewewewewewe wewewe12345
wewewewe wewe12345
```

This is the output

```
-------------Register-------------
Enter new username: wewe
['wewewewe']
['wewewewe', 'wewewewewewe']
['wewewewe', 'wewewewewewe', 'wewewewe']
Enter new password: wewe12345
```

Comment: From ```user = line.split()```, I think you text file looks like: ```abcd 1234```, with each account separated by a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this simple program I made:

```
def register():
    x=input("Enter username: ")
    y=input("Enter password: ")
    found=False
    with open('login.txt','r+') as file:
        file1=file.readlines()
        for line in file1:
            a,b=line.strip('\n').split()
            if a==x:
                found=True
                break
        if found:
            print("Username already exist.")
            register()
        else:
            file.write(x+' '+y+'\n')
register()
```

Let's run the program.

Before execution, the text file is empty
After executing the file:

```
Enter username: a
Enter password: b
```

Text file now:

```
a b
```

Sample execution number 2:

```
Enter username: a
Enter password: b
Username already exist.
Enter username: c
Enter password: d
```

Text file now:

```
a b
c d
```

Comment: @YonDaJun, Welcome! Please upvote and accept the answer ;=)